# Image between SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

```css
#home {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yB6Tc3mleuE/T4NkAKeazYI/AAAAAAAACB0/tlichKzIu3Q/s1600/Simple+unique+odd+weird+wallpapers+minimalistic+%2330+battleship+titanic.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.background {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#fg {
  fill: pink;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 1024px;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2s;
  animation: dash 2s;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1024px;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1024px;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}

#bg {
  fill: white;
  stroke: none;
  transform-origin: 1270px 550px;
  -webkit-animation: bgfill 2s linear 2s forwards;
  animation: bgfill 2s linear 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes bgfill {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(4);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bgfill {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(4);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="section" style="height:100vh;">
    <div class="background">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1376 764">
            <defs>
                <path id="shape" d="M1034.5,770.5a125.59,125.59,0,0,0-17-32c-12.32-16.72-25.68-25.84-33-31-6-4.23-59.88-42.55-100-90-13.64-16.14-20.57-24.48-26-38-15-37.48-3.73-73.65,0-85,8.68-26.45,23-43.26,35-57,19-21.82,33.56-29.9,67-54,33.68-24.27,55.39-39.91,77-60,40.56-37.69,35.94-49.35,81-96,34.18-35.39,51.27-53.08,79-65,7.79-3.35,76-31.44,140,2a142.06,142.06,0,0,1,31,22l7.5,7.5  L 1376,770.5 Z" />
            </defs>
            <use xlink:href="#shape" id="bg" />
            <use xlink:href="#shape" id="fg" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can not seem to make the background image visible at all times while remaining the same effect, making the fill transparent gets rid of the animation, I also tried to play around with z-index on various elements but without success, how can I make it so that the background image is visible inside the white line instead of the pink svg?

I also tried applying the same image to the pink SVG as fill and it kind of works, I just can not seem to make the image appear like how it would if it was full screen, it also makes the page a bit slow:

```
#fg {
  fill: url(#image);
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 1024px;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2s;
  animation: dash 2s;
}

<pattern id="image" width="1" height="1">
  <image xlink:href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yB6Tc3mleuE/T4NkAKeazYI/AAAAAAAACB0/tlichKzIu3Q/s1600/Simple+unique+odd+weird+wallpapers+minimalistic+%2330+battleship+titanic.jpg"></image>
</pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the pink with `fill-opacity`. But you would need to adjust the white "background" as it overlays the background-image.

You might need to change the shape for that.

You could also include the image as a layer in the svg.

```css
#home {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yB6Tc3mleuE/T4NkAKeazYI/AAAAAAAACB0/tlichKzIu3Q/s1600/Simple+unique+odd+weird+wallpapers+minimalistic+%2330+battleship+titanic.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.background {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#fg {
  fill: pink;
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 1024px;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2s;
  animation: dash 2s;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1024px;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1024px;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}

#bg {
  fill: white;
  opacity: .5;
  stroke: none;
  transform-origin: 1270px 550px;
  -webkit-animation: bgfill 2s linear 2s forwards;
  animation: bgfill 2s linear 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes bgfill {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(4);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bgfill {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(4);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="section" style="height:100vh;">
    <div class="background">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1376 764">
            <defs>
                <path id="shape" d="M1034.5,770.5a125.59,125.59,0,0,0-17-32c-12.32-16.72-25.68-25.84-33-31-6-4.23-59.88-42.55-100-90-13.64-16.14-20.57-24.48-26-38-15-37.48-3.73-73.65,0-85,8.68-26.45,23-43.26,35-57,19-21.82,33.56-29.9,67-54,33.68-24.27,55.39-39.91,77-60,40.56-37.69,35.94-49.35,81-96,34.18-35.39,51.27-53.08,79-65,7.79-3.35,76-31.44,140,2a142.06,142.06,0,0,1,31,22l7.5,7.5  L 1376,770.5 Z" />
            </defs>
            <use xlink:href="#shape" id="bg" />
            <use xlink:href="#shape" id="fg" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here would be a link if you want to try the image inside the svg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag

Comment: I would like to keep the white fill, I edited the code that shows my try on using fill to show the same image but I can not make it so that it only displays the bottom right part of the image

Comment: Where do you want the white fill? outside of the shape? if so, you need to rewrite your shape for your BG

Comment: Yeah outside of the white line, do you know what the shape should look like if I want to achieve it? I have no problems drawing it but I wouldn't know what it should look like

Comment: You could try the shape of the line and then increase the stroke to the left top...